# Java regex - parts of words

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to write regex in Java that matches word parts? For example I want to search for strings 'ab', 'cd' and 'ef'. A match should be returned in following examples:

```
[lab stef ecde], [lecde effe aaaab]
```

So a match should be returned if all strings ('ab', 'cd', 'ef') are parts of words anywhere in the text - order is not imported. 
However match shouldn't be returned if any of strings are missing

```
[lab stef]
```

Answer (score 6):

If it doesn't have to be regex then [Tichodroma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17471693/1393766) is the one you are looking for.

But if you really need to complicate your life and use regex you can try to use look-around mechanisms like [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) and create something like

```
"lab stef ecde".matches("(?=.*ab)(?=.*cd)(?=.*ef).*") //true
"lab stef".matches("(?=.*ab)(?=.*cd)(?=.*ef).*") //false
```

---

to explain it more clearly: in

```
(?=.*ab)(?=.*cd)(?=.*ef).*
```

- `(?=.*ab)` will check if your string contains `.*ab` where `.*` will match any characters before `ab` part.
- also look-ahead (?=...) is zero-width which means that it will reset cursor to the position where it was before look-ahead started so in our case it will still be at start of string
- this way we can use again `(?=.*cd)` and `(?=.*ef)`
- but we also need to include in our regex `.*` at the end, because `matches` check if entire string matches our regex, so we need to somehow iterate over entire string.

Answer (score 5):

Find every substring in the input and `&&` the resulting `boolean` values.

```
String s = "lab stef ecde";
boolean ab = s.indexOf("ab") > -1;
boolean cd = s.indexOf("cd") > -1;
boolean ef = s.indexOf("ef") > -1;
boolean match = ab && cd && ef; // true
```

**Edit**

In Germany there is a proverb:

> Warum einfach wenn es auch kompliziert geht?
>
> "Why simple when you can do it complicated?"

That's what I think about regular expressions in this case.

Comment: Yes, if you are matching constant strings, using a regex is a) more complicated than you need and b) more expensive.

Comment: Using this approach could also allow you to give good error reporting, way more easily than using regex. For instance, you could print a message "Error: Did not match ___" for each of the checks.

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev "parts of words anywhere in the text". He did not say anything about *different* words or about non-overlapping substrings.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
^.*(ab.*cd.*ef|ab.*ef.*cd|cd.*ab.*ef|cd.*ef.*ab|ef.*ab.*cd|ef.*cd.*ab).*$
```

You can test it here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

I believe it is an overkill though. Another optimized solution would be better.